# Can someone explain how to use Conv3d and ConvND in caffe?

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, video-processing, caffe

Can someone please, explain how one can use a `Conv3D` or a `ConvND` for `Depth-images` or videos or pretty much any 3d (n-d?) data in `Caffe` ?
Is there any example or demo for Conv3D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular `"Convolution"` layer to process blobs of any dimension. You only need to pay close attention to the parameters:

```
layer {
  type: "Convolution"
  name: "conv_nd"
  bottom: "in" # 5D blob 
  too: "out"
  convolution_param {
     kernel_size: 3
     kernel_size: 5
     kernel_size: 5 # define 3 by 5 by 5 kernel

     pad: 1
     pad: 2
     pad: 2  # pad according to kernel size

     stride: 1
     stride: 2
     stride: 2 # you can have different stride for different dimensions

     axis: 1  # the "channel" dimension
     num_output: 30 # output 30 dim per 3D voxel
  }
}
```

For more information read the comments on Convolution param in the [caffe.proto file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L558-L609).

Comment: `3 by 5 by 5` = `depth by height by width` am I right? @Shai

Comment: @thigi frankly, I am not 100% sure about the order of dimensions here. you might need to give it a try.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks, so tell me if I'm right. suppose I have 5 200x200 color frames for input, and my first conv layer has 10 outputs (num_output). 
How is this Conv3D take place? as apposed to the normal Conv2D,  there is a kernel, applied on the input, gives a new featuremap.so in conv2d we will have 10 feature maps.
In Conv3D, each kernel is applied on each frame, creates a feature map for each, the result is stacked together. so the end output of the first layer will be 10*7 feature maps?

Comment: @shai: 
and also how are  those padding, strides used? 
one pad is used for spatial extend, one stride is also used for the same thing.
when the padding is different, two are used for width and height respectively. what does 3 mean here? 
How does padding or stride make sense for temporal extend?

Comment: if you have 5 temporal frames with 1 channel per frame, then you have 1-by-5-by-200-by-200 input. If `num_output: 10` then the output will be `10-by-5-by-200-by-200` (assuming you pad according to kernel_size).

Comment: @Shai: Arent they stacked? like normal feature maps? (in normal case, 10 kernels creates a volume of 10 feature maps.(10x200x200)
In this case, is it like normal, or is it like, batch_num, volume of (5x200x200)? 
If its the first one, the rest of the network would have 2d inputs right? 
but in the second one, the temporal section is preserved.
and by the way, if each frame is colorful, it should not make any difference right? still we should have (10x5x200x200) right? 

Thank you very much

Comment: @thigi "does not work" because of `"xavier"` filler?

Comment: @thigi so everything is good now? can you please delete your comments stating this solution does not work?

Comment: @Shai: Could you look at my question and give me some guidance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310081/how-to-store-volumetric-patch-into-hdf5